# Can a noun be both a subject and an object at the same time?

Tags: relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, whom, parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles

> John Knight, *who/whom* I spoke to yesterday, seemed to be rather irritable.

In this sentence, *John Knight* is an object because *I* (the subject) am speaking to him; however, he is also a subject since he is performing an action, which in this case, is being irritable. Is he both a subject and an object? If not, which one of these is he?

Furthermore, which is correct: *who* or *whom*?

Comment: John Knight is subject of "seemed". It is also the antecedent to "who(m)", which is object complement of the preposition "to" in the relative clause. In that respect, John Knight plays two roles: subject and antecedent, which I think is what you're getting at.

Answer (score 2):

## No

The same word cannot be doing two different jobs at once.

> John Knight, who/whom I spoke to yesterday, seemed to be rather irritable.

Your thesis that *John Knight* is “both” a subject and an object here is where you’ve gone wrong. Your syntactic analysis is off, in that it isn’t ever an object here. It is only the subject, the subject of the verb *seem*.

In contrast, the subject of your subordinate clause is *I* and the object is the relative pronoun *who/whom*.

Which provides you your answer: it should “really” be *whom* in careful speech and writing, since it’s the object not the subject. This “really” bit is that this is a “rule” that not all native speakers and writers are aware of — or even if they are aware of, choose to follow.

Comment: Oeuf corse. I agree completely.

Comment: Sort of. ***Sit yourself down***.

Comment: How about "I told John yesterday when John was working." Isn't John both an object and a subject in this sentence?